# Convert string Ex: "Friday, 11 of november of 2022" to DateTime C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, parsing

**EDIT:** I am reading from an Excel Report using ExcelDataReader.DataSet and reading a string cell to convert to DateTime. Added a pic showing where is located the cell with the string

[image: DataTable Visualizer]

```
dataSet = reader.AsDataSet();
DataTable = dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
foreach (DataRow fila in dataTable.Rows)
{
    // "Miercoles, 16 de Noviembre de 2022  15:21"
    string dateString = fila["Column18"].ToString();
    // I remove the hour as is not necessary
    dateString = dateString.Remove(dateString.Length-7); 
    string format = @"dddd, d \o\f MMMM \o\f yyyy";
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-PY"));
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
```

But I get This error format exception:

- ```
    $exception  {"The string 'Miercoles, 16 de Noviembre de 2022  15:21' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index '0'."}  System.FormatException
  ```

Comment: What's the excel format? is it custom or a date type?

Comment: What format string did you use with `TryParseExact()`?

Comment: The long date pattern for English is `dddd, MMMM d, yyyy` (i.e: `Friday, August 5, 2023`) so you should modify the pattern of your translation to match the correct expected English datetime format. However parsing the Spanish long date with the correct culture info (`es-PY`) is working well.

Comment: XLS format, I use ExcelDataReader for reading the Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works fine for me

```cs
string s = "Viernes, 18 de noviembre de 2022";

var es = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es");
if (DateTime.TryParse(s, es, out DateTime date)) {
    Console.WriteLine(date);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("parse error");
}
```

Obviously, the word "de" is recognized as valid part of a Spanish date.

Note that the weekday name must match with the date. Otherwise you get a parse error.

---

The problem with `"Miercoles, 16 de Noviembre de 2022  15:21"` is that the weekday name should have an accent: **Miércoles**. Therefore, we get a parsing error.

We can fix this by stripping away the weekday name, since it is not required for the date to be complete:

```cs
var es = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es");

int index = dateString.IndexOf(',');
if (index >= 0) {
    dateString = dateString.Substring(index + 1);
}
if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, es, out DateTime date)) {
    Console.WriteLine(date);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("parse error");
}
```

Comment: Same error as with .ParseExact or .Parse as with the other answer and edited my post adding more info explaining my issue.

Comment: Hecking time, IT WORKS
some details DateTime.TryParse complains when using "es":
- No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 3 arguments
There are not 3 arguments only 1,2,4:
1 : string only 
2: string/out DateTime
4: string, culture, DateTimeStyle, out DateTime.

I am using .NET 6 Console project Windows OS.
With 2 arguments as 4 works great.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am using .NET 7. It may have a new overload with 3 arguments. I think the one with 4 arguments is better than the one with only two, because if you run your application on a computer having a different culture than `es`, I will fail.

Answer (score 4):

You can escape the `of` (`de`) strings and use the correct format specifiers for each part:

```
    string dateString = "Tuesday, 7 of March of 2023";
    string format = @"dddd, d \o\f MMMM \o\f yyyy";
    var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
    Console.WriteLine(date);
```

or the spanish version:

```
string dateString = "Martes, 7 de Marzo de 2023";
string format = @"dddd, d \d\e MMMM \d\e yyyy";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-MX"));
```

Note that March 7, 2023 is a Tuesday, not a Wednesday, so the parsing of your example would fail because it's the wrong day of the week.

Comment: yes the other example was wrong as well, August 5th is a Saturday.

Comment: I added more info for clarification and tried .ParseExact but I get a format exception error

Comment: Thanks for the extra information, the other answer shows what was wrong, so I gave the answer correct but yours was right too and thanks for the clarification with format.